# Ubuntu starts only when I boot from my flash drive

Tags: 12.04, installation, boot, grub2, boot-failure

I have installed the Ubuntu 12.04 using a bootable USB. The installation went fine but after the installation there was just a blank screen with the cursor blinking and Ubuntu wasn't starting. Maybe that was an installation error but when I booted again from my USB surprisingly Ubuntu started working. Even if I remove the USB after the initial boot, Ubuntu keeps working fine. Do I have to boot from my USB each time I restart my computer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### The problem

Grub, Ubuntu's bootloader, was installed on the flash drive, and not on your internal hard drive, as it should have been.

### Solution

Boot with the flash drive plugged in. Remove it once Ubuntu is booted up.

Run the following commands from a Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
boot-repair
```

Click on the "Recommended repair" button, and reboot.

#### Explanation

Boot-Repair installed Grub to your internal hard drive. This allows your computer to boot without depending on the bootloader that was installed on the flash drive.

---

#### Glossary

> **[Bootloader](http://www.cs.tau.ac.il/telux/lin-club_files/linux-boot/slide0002.htm)**: a piece of code that runs before any operating system is running. A bootloader is used to boot other operating
>   systems. Each operating system usually has its own bootloader.
>
> **[GRUB (*Grand Unified Bootloader*)](http://searchenterpriselinux.techtarget.com/definition/GRUB-GRand-Unified-Bootloader)**: a bootloader package developed to support multiple operating systems and allow the user to select among them during boot-up. It is Ubuntu's default bootloader.
>
> **[Command, command line](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: the traditional Unix environment , where you type commands to tell the computer what to do.
>
> **[Terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal/)**: an application that allows you to access the command line. Open it by hitting its keyboard shortcut, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Alt</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd>

Comment: charlo
when and where will the "recommend repair" button appear?
at the end this appeared in the terminal
"W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs"

Comment: As soon as Boot-Repair is installed. Give it time. :) Are you connected to the internet?

Comment: yes i am connected to the internet.
it ended like this in the terminal:
W: Failed to fetch cdrom://Ubuntu 12.04 LTS _Precise Pangolin_ - Release i386 (20120423)/dists/precise/restricted/binary-i386/Packages  Please use apt-cdrom to make this CD-ROM recognized by APT. apt-get update cannot be used to add new CD-ROMs


E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

zaigham@Zaigham-Inspiron-N4050:~$

Comment: btw how do you remember these lengthy commands. One should have an excellent memory to remember all these commands =)

Comment: Ok, try them individually then. `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair`, then `sudo apt-get update`, then `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair`, and finally `boot-repair`. And I **don't** remember them ;)

Answer (score 0):

As SirCarlo says on his answer, this is caused for not installing mbr on the internel drive.

I prefer this solution myself.

1. Boot to the Ubuntu using USB drive.
2. Open a terminal and use this command

   ```
   sudo grub-install /dev/sda
   ```
3. Then this command

   ```
   sudo update-grub
   ```

**Note:** If you have more than one hard drive, including USB drive, the system assigns letter `a`, `b`, `c` ... to them. Such as `/dev/sda` for First hard disk, `/dev/sdb` for second hard disk. Use `sudo blkid` command to see the actual hard disk letter for your internal drive.

Comment: but I am still not sure why grub was installed on my USB drive instead of the hard drive. Is it some kind of bug in the installation, because I see many other guys are having the same problem.
 Thanks btw

Comment: @Laphanga that can be another question. It may be because, it is booted from USB. When you select a partition in local hard drive, the boot device changes to `/dev/sda`. But it requires some secs. may be you clicked "install" button very quickly. This is only my assumption. I'm not sure exactly.